# HIstory command only showing last 15 commands

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, terminal, zsh

I enter the command `history` 
It shows the last 15 commands, where are the previous 988 commands.

```
  989  yarn android
  990  /Dir/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command ; exit;
  991  yarn android
  992  source ~/.bashrc
  993  cd Documents
  994  ls
  995  rm -rf firebase_dummy_app
  996  expo init
  997  cd firesbaseDummy
  998  yarn android
  999  cd ..
 1000  rm -rf firesbaseDummy
 1001  /Dir/firesbaseDummy/node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command ; exit;
 1002  /Dir/firebaseChat/node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command ; exit;
 1003  history
 1004  history
```

Even if I grep them `history | grep 'rm'` for something I know I did, none of the previous commands show up

If I continue to enter terminal commands the numbers go up but I'm still limited to only 15. (command 995-1010 will be shown for example

It continues happening when I close the end the terminal app and reopen it

The terminal is zsh on MacOS Catalina

Comment: I've found out a work around is opening `.zsh_history` but I would still like to know why the command isn't working

Comment: `echo 'alias history="history 1"' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc && history`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `history n` command, where `n` is a number shows all history since line n. So in your case, `history 904` will show the last 100 commands.

Comment: So why is regular history only the last 15? Do I have a default set to 15 or something? Where could I change this default?

Comment: Yes the default is set to 15. If it was too long you'd have to scroll through an entire list to find what you might want. I don't think you can change this as a setting, as it is a built-in command

Comment: I think it was different in the `sh` shell. Catalina runs `zsh` instead of `sh` and this is the first time I've noticed it

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the other day as well when I updated to zsh.

Comment: If you want to display everything, you can just type history 1.

Comment: Add this to your .zshrc for a semi workaround:
hist() { if [ $1 -eq 15 ]; then history; else history 1; fi; }

Comment: `history` also supports negative numbers to show the most recent `n` commands. e.g. `history -100` will show the last 100 commands.

Comment: But what about **all** the lines? if you do a grep your want **all** the line and not 904 lines.

Comment: `echo 'alias history="history 1"' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc && history`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `zsh`on my ubuntu and when I run `history` it shows me 285 commands, all the history so far. Don't know what's happening but pretty sure it wasn't supposed to do that. I'm  using [Oh my Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/), don't know if that helps.

Comment: I think it might be a MacOS Catalina thing

Comment: Yeah, maybe it is